# What's been wrong with the alternate-world tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed that we have an [alternate-world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-world) tag. I perused the (7) questions  using it and noticed that most of them really didn't have much to do with alternate worlds. They all would be perfectly identifiable with only  the other tags they used. Does anyone else think that these questions poorly use the tag, or that we don't need the tag at all?

Comment: I do think they are useless. Most worlds will be alternate worlds anyway. Those that are not can use: history, Earth or other tags.

Comment: Worth bearing in mind that there's a proposal for alternate histories at the moment - I'm arguing they should be on topic here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79097/alternative-history

Comment: Perhaps altering the tag to [tag:alternate-earth] would be better?

Comment: @Liath Ahh, I remember that question. I'm not sure if changing the tag name would be good or bad; it's an interesting idea, though.

Comment: I believe alternate history is also on topic

Comment: Alternate History indeed is on topic.

Comment: Sure, alternate history is on-topic. But the tag is being improperly used, which is the issue I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already have an [earth-like](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth-like) tag that functions to define worlds as earth like in all ways except those specified in the question.

As defined [alternate-world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-world) is redundant, and less descriptive in it's meaning.  Alternate can mean totally unlike Earth or like Earth (just the English definitions I mean, the meaning is well spelled out in the tag definition)